# Подключение общего проекта TFS в другие проекты

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, dll, tfs

У меня есть 3 проекта в TFS, один это Web Application, второй DLL, третий это Console Application.

Мне надо добавить в первый и третий проект ссылку на второй так, чтобы она автоматически обновлялась и была доступна любому разработчику.

Как это можно сделать?

Как я думаю, в решения с Web applicatoin и Console Application я могу добавить существующий (второй) проект с DLL? Это правильный путь? При этом для всех разработчиков он будет автоматически подтягиваться из TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете добавить ссылки на проекты и всё будет подтягиваться.

Рассмотрите также возможность сборки проекта DLL на сборочном сервере и упаковывайте артефакты в nuget-пакет.

Разработчики отдельных приложений смогут подтягивать нужные версии пакетов и самостоятельно решать, где и какую версию использовать.

Это, пожалуй, самый гибкий и удобный путь, особенно когда у вас не корпоративное приложение, существующее в одном экземпляре, а приложение, которое установлено у клиентов и вам приходится поддерживать несколько веток.